# Stacked Div Order in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 grids. In big screens I have content in 2 columns, side by side.
The left column is a single div and the right column is made of 2 divs, like this:

```
(left)
col-md-6
div 1
col-md-6

(right)
col-md-6
div 2
div 3
col-md-6
```

I would like for them to stack in this order when the screen is small:

```
div 2
div 1
div 3
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
      <div class="well hidden-xs">Div 1</div>
      <div class="well visible-xs">Div 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
          <div class="well hidden-xs">Div 2</div>
          <div class="well visible-xs">Div 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12">
          <div class="well">Div 3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm getting all 3 divs in a single row on a big screen using this solution. And the rightmost div is still not in the center when stacked on a small screen. Maybe if you indicate div numbers in your example?

Comment: So you want the divs in the right div to be inline with each other or one on top of the other on a large screen?

Comment: The divs on the right should be on top of one another. And the order when stacked on a small screen should be: 1. top right div, 2. left div, 3. bottom right div.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for is possible due to the way you have to nest in bootstrap. I added some updated code above in my example. See if that helps you at all.

Comment: Just updated the code above, check it out and see if that works.

Comment: Both answers are correct. This is marked as accepted only because it includes an actual code example

Comment: Thanks @Augusto! Glad we could help out.

Answer (score 3):

Write div 1 two times one at left(where it is already placed) and second in between the div 2 and div 3 of right column. Now use class visible-xl in left column div 1 and visible-xs in right column div 1 which is placed in between div 2 and 3. By this the div 1 in left column will be visible in the large screen as it is and in small screen that will hide and div 1 of right column will be visible . Thus atumatical it will appear as your mentioned order in small device and big screen device.

Comment: It makes sense, and I guess it would work for static content. However I have a form inside the div that would have to be repeated so I guess I couldn't use this solution.

Comment: Anil's answer is pretty much the only way you'd be able to accomplish this (that I know of). I created what he's saying in my example above.

Comment: What is your codeing language ? If it support partial page or html helper to reuse a portion of a div like in asp.net mvc then I don't think it will a problem .second by this approach you are not going against to bootstrap recommended ways to accomplish this this.

Comment: You are right. A partial would work. I'm on Rails. I'll try it and report back.